# how to redirect to specific folder/page with htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to force url
https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/test/ to https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/index.php/ with help of .htaccess

here test (https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/test/) is ot fixed it is dynamic value

my current code

```
     RewriteEngine On

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(xyz\.)?abc\.


# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /index\.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please use the `edit` button below your question and revise it. Try to be ore precise. What do you actually want? Which URL is the one to be actually requested (used in the browser) and which is to be called internally (assuming you are working towards an internal rewrite)?

Comment: And if you setup those rules you posted, then why are you not able to add the simple additional rewriting rule you are asking for?

Comment: @arkascha that is the main problem

Comment: @arkascha  whenever i paste ther url in browser like https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/test/ or https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/test001/  i wanted to force that url goes to https://xyz.abc.net/abc_api/index.php/

Comment: You just need to add a rewriting for that specific path prefix prior to the other rewriting rules you already have implemented.